# JSON return from a web API can be double or long, how do I most efficiently deal with this in Java?

Tags: java, json, double, long-integer, type-conversion

I'm writing some code in java and using the JSON Simple package. I run this code below

```
jsonObject.get( "last" ) ;
```

Unfortunately this can either be a long or a double, what is the fastest/most correct way of parsing this value?

Would it be something like the following?

```
long lngLast = -1;
double dblLast = -1;

if ( jsonObject.get( "last" ).getClass().getName() == "java.lang.Long" ) {
    lngLast =  (long) jsonObject.get( "last" ) ;
} else {
    dblLast = (double) jsonObject.get("last");
}

if ( lngLast == -1)
    System.out.println( dblLast );
else
    System.out.println( lngLast );
```

This seems absurd. There must be a better way of doing this. I've attempted converting the long to a double (which I believe I am supposed to be able to do?) but I get errors every time. I'm hoping someone can educate me on the correct or better way to do this.

Comment: *Why* can it be a double or a long? *This* is the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In reality, the "last" element should have a consistent data type in all the JSON messages you're dealing with. Without a proper spec and without wanting to test, you'd probably want to go with `double` over a `long`.

In the case you have, where the type can be either, I think testing the object type is a perfectly fine way to do it.

As a side note, your if test should really be:

```
if (jsonObject.get("last").getClass().equals(Long.class)) {
    ....
}
```

Using `==` for String comparison will not work as you'd want it to.

Comment: Yes, I would have hoped it would a consistent data type, but it isn't. It seems the JSON parser determines what it is, I tried to see if I could set types or whatever, but I am unable to find anything.

Comment: You mean the JSON library is deciding which type it will be? Are you using the one from [json.org](http://json.org/java/)? If that's the case, I would say you should treat it as a `double`. If the number doesn't contain a period `.` then it will treat it as `long` (or `int`)

Comment: No, it is the json-simple package (https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) - I used it forever ago due to its simplicity. I may have to try changing packages.

Comment: If you're going for a new one, I've had great experiences with the [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) library.